# Type 'Int!' has no subscript members

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct

I get an error when I added an integer to a struct and want to use in the UITableview. This is the code:

```
struct Mijnproducten {
    var productname : String!
    var prodID : Int!
    var productdesc : String!
    var productline : [String]!
    var expanded : Bool!

    init(productname: String, prodID: Int,productdesc: String, productline: [String], expanded: Bool)
    {
        self.productname = productname
        self.prodID = prodID
        self.productdesc = productdesc
        self.productline = productline
        self.expanded = false
    }

}
```

UITableviewcontroller:

Retrieve the information from alamofire request:

```
  for (_, dict) in jsonArray {
                    let thisObject = Mijnproducten(productname: dict["productname"].string!, prodID: dict["tagID"].int!, productdesc: dict["productdesc"].string!, productline: ["Description", "History", "Transfer"], expanded: false )
                    self.mijnproducten01.append(thisObject) }
```

In this function I use the variable:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labelCell") as! RowTableViewCell

        Cell.ProductLine.text = mijnproducten01[indexPath.section].productline[indexPath.row]
        var Tags = String(mijnproducten01[indexPath.section].prodID[indexPath.row])
        Cell.UUID.text = Tags
        return Cell
    }
```

error is visible at the line:

```
var Tags = String(mijnproducten01[indexPath.section].prodID[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: `prodID` is not an array, so what do you expect that `prodID[indexPath.row]` returns?

Comment: `mijnproducten01[indexPath.section].prodID` That's should return the `prodID` from your struct that is a `Int`. It doesn't make sense at all to call `prodID[indexPath.row]` after. If you decompose: `let myMijnproducten: Mijnproducten = mijnproducten01[indexPath.section]`. Then you want `var Tags = String(myMijnproducten.prodID)`?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but important info: you are initializing all values, so there's no need to use implicitly unwrapped optionals. No need for `!`. Just declare `var prodID: Int` instead of `var prodID: Int!` for example. Also note that an optional array rarely makes sense. You can express the absence of value by an empty array.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments! I fixed it indeed with leaving the indexpath.row. It is clear that it is not needed. for the productline I needed it because it is an array. @Moritz, thank you, I will use this info.